# Download powershell (.ps1) file via ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, powershell, web-config

I've got a `.ps1` file that I would like to link readers to. Unfortunately, navigating to that URL only results in a 404. If memory serves, this is being "blocked" just like `.config` files, but there's a way to change that configuration in `web.config` ... but I can't seem to find the correct thing via search.

TL;DR, how can I expose a `.ps1` powershell script so that it's accessible (*though not executable, obviously*) via HTTP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you need to add a MIME type for .ps1. In your IIS Manager, select the server node on the tree, and click "MIME Types". Then click "Add..." on the right panel. For extension, set it to `.ps1`, and set the MIME type to `text/plain`.

Now IIS should serve .ps1 files.

You could use a MIME Type of `application/octet-stream` instead of `text/plain`. Using the former will cause most browsers to download it rather than try to display it.

You can do this for a specific web application or virtual directory, too. If you are doing this through web.config, it would look something like this:

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ps1" mimeType="text/plain" /><!-- or application/octet-stream -->
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

We used this same strategy for continuous integration with IIS static site resources - the powershell to do this same action is below in case this helps others wishing to script this change for CI. We were receiving HTTP 404s when asking for unlisted or non-standard file types (*sql, ps1, etc.*).

#### Add Additional Static MIME Type to IIS (`.ps1`)

```bsh
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty  -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.webServer/staticContent" -name "." -AtElement @{fileExtension='.ps1'}

Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.webServer/staticContent" -name "." -value @{fileExtension='.ps1';mimeType='text/plain'}
```

This is re-entrant to support repeatable release deployments / desired state, etc.